# Sending delegate as an id instead of setting it as a property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, delegates

I have a class object that i'm using a lot from different places.

Now i'm using the class like this:

```
myClass.delegate = self;
[myClass doSomething];
```

doSomething creates a new class object that calculate stuff and can take up to 1 min before it sends back a result to the delegate like this:

```
-(void)doSomething {
   CalculateStuff *calc = [[calculateStuff alloc] init];
   calc.delegate = self;
   [calc calculate];
}

/* Calculate Delegate */
-(void)didCalculate {
   [[self delegate] didDoSomething];
}
```

Problem is that i from another place is calling the same thing it will call my latest delegate and this causes a lot of problems.

**Question:**

Is there a way to send the delegate as an object without having to set it as the property?
I've written it like this and Xcode give me warnings "Incomplete implementation of MyClass"

```
[myClass doSomethingWithDelegate:self];
```

And

```
-(void)doSomethingWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
   CalculateStuff *calc = [[calculateStuff alloc] init];
   [calc calculateWithDelegate:delegate];
}

/* Calculate Delegate */
-(void)didCalculateWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
   [delegate didDoSomething];
}
```

**EDIT**
Just tried it out and it seems to work, but how can i get rid of the warnings in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you forgot to remove the declaration of `doSomething` and `didCalculate` from your class's interface (or class extension).

---

Ideally you should create a protocol to ensure that your delegate has the required method(s).  For instance:

```
@protocol DoSomethingDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didDoSomething;
@end
```

Then use `id<DoSomethingDelegate>` instead of just `id`.

---

Passing a block would also be a valid solution to this problem, although it's a bit trickier.

Comment: I have defined the protocol. Problem was i forgot to change the declaration (was rewriting the code). How silly of me. Thanks anyway!